# How can I get a tag's (eg. div, or other) value by parameter name?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I'am new in Python and I run in a problem.
There is a website where that site has a complete structure. I know how can I find a div, or other tag, but when I found that tag (eg. with class name), I would like to gathering all parameters with value, but I can't.
So, My question is how can I gathering a random tag's all parameters and values after I found that?

How I found:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
.
.
.
soup = BS(page.content, 'html.parser')
soup.prettify()
div = soup.find('div', {'class':'abc'})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get all the element's attributes, simply use the [`.attrs` property](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#attributes):

```
print(div.attrs)
```

This would print out a dictionary where keys are attribute names and values are attribute values.

Comment: Ahg, You are right. Thanks a lot. And I saw can I use severally too.
print(div.attrs[atrname])

Comment: @Pisti yeah, if you need to get a single attribute by name, you can also treat a "Tag" as a dictionary: `div[attrname]`. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks a lot again. have a nice day!